# sbbi upnp library java

Tags: java, firewall, router, upnp, ports

I have developed an application that needs to map some **ports**. For that reason I use `sbbi-upnp library`. It worked perfectly until I changed my router. My new router is `technicolor td5130`.

When I run my code everything seems to work fine and the **ports** seem to be mapped but I cannot have access to the `"server"` in the real world. When I manually map the ports via the router's web interface everything works fine. I have already tested **firewall** reasons.

I use the method

```
boolean mapped=device.addPortMapping("Server", null, port, port, hostIP, 0, "TCP");
```

mapped is `true` and everything seems to be fine but isn't.

My new router has only one option: `"enable or disable upnp"`. Of course I have it **enabled**.

I suppose that it has `sth` to do with the router settings that I cannot change via web interface but i m not sure. Is there anyone that has any suggestion ?